# Remove whitespace when input autocomplete text in Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, removing-whitespace

In register activity, focus the email EditTextField(not autocompletext just edittext), I can put the email that I use frequently.

but it always input email with white space.

Like, if frequently using email is 'tester@test.com'

but when I select the email at keyboard, it input with whitespace 'tester@test.com '

I want remove the white space when I select the email with autocomplete

If you know about that, please help me

---

I put this at public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)

```
Log.d(TAG,"print input email " + "|" + editTextEmail.getText().toString() + "|");

D/JoinActivity: print input email |tester@tester|
D/JoinActivity: print input email |tester@tester|
D/JoinActivity: print input email |tester@tester |
```

---

when I put in after textchanged,

It print repeat like this,

```
2019-03-13 17:55:31.208 24374-24565/? D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=418
2019-03-13 17:55:31.208 24374-24565/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=418
2019-03-13 17:55:31.208 14842-14842/com.example.thewell_dev.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=79
2019-03-13 17:55:31.209 14842-14842/com.example.thewell_dev.myapplication D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=82
2019-03-13 17:55:31.217 14842-14842/com.example.thewell_dev.myapplication V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@8a6ddd0 nm : com.example.thewell_dev.myapplication ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@58201c9
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

inside your editText.addTextChangedListener{....}

add this

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
 editText.setText(result);
 }
```

**OR**

```
@Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 String result= s.trim();
 editText.setText(result);

 }
```

Comment: I don't know why it occurs error, but it helps me. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TextWatcher to your EditText that watches for changes to the text and removes leading/trailing white space.

Comment: yes, I add watcher at editext, but when autocomplete, it can't be done

Comment: But the TextWatcher callback should still be triggered when the user selects an autocomplete option and the text gets put into the EditText.

Comment: Yes I can get it but when I select the autocomplete, it print three times

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What prints three times and where?

Comment: I update my question, it print three times when I select the suggested autocomplete

Comment: I try another way, setOnFocusChanged at edtitext. Thank you for your answer